# Wireshark capturing only protocols SSDP, NBNS, LLMNR etc

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, network-protocols

I'm running Wireshark on my Ubuntu laptop and trying to capture WLAN traffic from my Windows laptop, but I can only see protocols as mentioned in the title: SSDP, LLMNR, NBNS, MDNS, IGMPv3.

Monitoring WLAN traffic from another Ubuntu laptop worked perfectly. I had set it up according to Wireshark documentation and I was able to see all decrypted traffic when I was connected to router and when I was offline in monitor mode. The problems started when I was trying to monitor traffic from Windows laptop. Is this some common behavior when monitoring traffic from different operating system?

Comment: Does your network have APs on different radio channels?

Comment: By radio channels do you mean the same as wifi frequency?

Comment: Yes. Even with monitor mode, you can only see things on a single frequency, not all of them.

Comment: Frequency is the same, so it's not because of that.